# how to download a file from server

Tags: react-native

i am working with react native project i have a task to doawnload files and store them in local so use RNFS but i have links like this .../api/v1/files/5e6f831588b03d4ba3d9f69c/download where i use it in chrome it start the download but with in react native it didn't download anything

here is my code

```
 const localFile = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/test2.pdf`;

    const options = {
      fromUrl:
        '.../api/v1/files/5e6f831588b03d4ba3d9f69c/download', //... means the server base url the link is totaly right
      toFile: localFile,
    };
    RNFS.downloadFile(options)
      .promise.then(() => FileViewer.open(localFile))
      .then(() => {
        // success
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // error
      });
  }
```

Comment: Have you added permissions to write storage?

Comment: it's not about permissions cz i download other files from web and its work